# jQuery val() function not replacing String correctly

Tags: jquery

So how the code was supposed to work is that "Logged in as" is being replaced by "Hello":

```
$("strong:contains('Logged in as:')").val(function (i, w) {
  return w.replace("Logged in as:", "Hello");
});
```

Answer (score 2):

If you have non input or textarea you need to use [text()](http://api.jquery.com/text/) or [html()](http://api.jquery.com/html/) instead of [val()](http://api.jquery.com/val/)

```
$("strong:contains('Logged in as:')").text(function(i,w){return w.replace("Logged in as:","Hello");});
```

or

```
$("strong:contains('Logged in as:')").html(function(i,w){return w.replace("Logged in as:","Hello");});
```

Answer (score 1):

Assuming

```
$("strong:contains('Logged in as:')")
```

works correctly

use:

```
$("strong:contains('Logged in as:')").text("Hello")
```

Answer (score 0):

try this

$("strong:contains('Logged in as:')").html("Hello");

Answer (score 0):

I ran into a similar problem not too long ago, strangely I resolved it by breaking the statement in 2 lines. The first assigns the value to a var and the second calls `val`.